# Tensorflow federated increase default_serialization_limit_bytes

Tags: serialization, tensorflow-federated

I'm doing federated learning with tensorflow federated

```
for round_num in range(5):
    state, metrics = trainer.next(state, federated_train_data)
    print('Round {r}, Metrics: {m}'.format(r=round_num, m=metrics))
```

this is my code and it's give this error

```
ValueError: Serialized size of Dataset (537613688 bytes) exceeds maximum allowed (104857600 bytes)
```

I have try the following code to increase the limit but the function doesn't exist anymore in the tensorflow federated version 0.58

```
tf.data.experimental.serialization.set_serialization_options(
    total_bytes_limit=1073741824
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may increase the serialization limit of the dataset in the `value_serialization.py` script under `tensorflow_federated` library directory.

In line 46 you can change the sequence size to:

```
 _DEFAULT_MAX_SERIALIZED_SEQUENCE_SIZE_BYTES = 500 * (1024**2)  # 500 MB
```

or to any other limit that suits you best.

I honestly do not know if this change has any consequences in general, but it worked for me.